# Bootstrap datepicker, handle event besides changeDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to capture an event when the user:

from -> to (added this to be clear, first calendar is from, second is to)

- 1) Enters a from date, and a to date
- 2) Enters a to date
- 3) Enters a from date, then clicks off leaving the auto selected from date(or what was previously there

The issue I am having is capturing that click off.  I tried using `'changeDate blur'` event with no luck.  The blur piece breaks the ability to change the second date i.e the todate.  If I just rely on the `'changeDate'` event I cannot capture scenario number three above (or at least I don't know how).

**Here's my source code:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function () {
        var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        var checkin = $('#results_enter_fromdate').datepicker({
            onRender: function (date) {
                return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
            }
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
                var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                checkout.setValue(newDate);
            }
            checkin.hide();
            $('#results_enter_todate')[0].focus();
        }).data('datepicker');
        var checkout = $('#results_enter_todate').datepicker({
            onRender: function (date) {
                return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
            }
        }).on('changeDate blur', function (ev) {
            checkout.hide();
            //something here would run in all three scenarios, but
            //including 'blur' above breaks the ability to enter the todate
            //to anything besides the data immediately after the fromdate
        }).data('datepicker');
    });
</script>
```

**From Bootstrap**: can be found [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want - https://jsfiddle.net/4L9p9z1r/2/ - I may have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: No that doesn't appear to cover what I am asking.  I am trying to understand why adding the 'blur' would break my ability to change the todate field.  Or how to capture the click off without selecting a date.